# forEach() anonymous function not defined error

Tags: javascript

I am getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined" in chrome console. What is wrong with the forEach? Am I using the forEach() function correctly here?Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="d3.min.js">
```

```
<body>


<!--Place all DOM elements here -->


<script>

//Write your code here
var data = [132,71,337,93,78,43,20,16,30,8,17,21];
//console.log(data[0]);

var donut = {key:"Glazed", value: 132};
//console.log(donut.key, donut.value);

var donuts = [
    {key:"Glazed",    value: 132},
    {key:"Jelly",     value: 71},
    {key:"Holes",     value: 337},
    {key:"Sprinkles", value: 93}
];
//console.log(donuts[1].key, donuts[1].value);
/*
for(var i = 0, len = donuts.length; i < len; i++){
    console.log(donuts[i].key, donuts[i].value);
}
*/

donuts.forEach(function(entry){
    console.log(donuts[i].key, donuts[i].value);
});
```

```
</body>
```

Comment: It's a simple typo/editing error; vote to close and move on. You have no `i` variable in your version using `forEach`. Use `entry` instead of `donuts[i]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has to be this way:

```
donuts.forEach(function(entry, i){
    console.log(donuts[i].key, donuts[i].value);
});
```

or better without index:

```
donuts.forEach(function(donut){
    console.log(donut.key, donut.value);
});
```

Comment: Worth mentioning the declaration of `i` is commented out.

Answer (score 0):

For each should take a parameter, if called with any object. There are different ways to use foreach. This link will be useful to you.[Foreach different usage...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 0):

```
var donuts = [
    {key: "Glazed", value: 132},
    {key: "Jelly", value: 71},
    {key: "Holes", value: 337},
    {key: "Sprinkles", value: 93}
];

// Using a for loop
console.log("Using a for loop:");
for (var i = 0; i < donuts.length; i++) {
    console.log(donuts[i].key, donuts[i].value);
}

// Using forEach
console.log("\nUsing forEach:");
donuts.forEach(function(entry) {
    console.log(entry.key, entry.value);
});

// Using for...of loop (ES6+)
console.log("\nUsing for...of loop:");
for (const donut of donuts) {
    console.log(donut.key, donut.value);
}

// Using Object.entries() (ES8+)
console.log("\nUsing Object.entries():");
Object.entries(donuts).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    console.log(value.key, value.value);
});
```